# Customize Hyprlinkr to use the name of a route's template

Tags: hyprlinkr

#### Context

Given the following route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FooBarBazRoute",
    routeTemplate: "foo-bar-baz/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "FooBarBaz",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

and by using Hyprlinkr

```
var linker = new RouteLinker(this.Request);
var id = "813bafcc-8329-<trimmed>"
var href = this
    .linker
    .GetUri<FooBarBazController>(
        c => c.Get(id))
    .ToString()
```

the value of `href` looks like this:

```
"http://d59503db-1e96-<trimmed>/foobarbaz/813bafcc-8329-<trimmed>"
```

#### Question

Is it possible to customize Hyprlinkr so that `href` looks like:

```
"http://d59503db-1e96-<trimmed>/foo-bar-baz/813bafcc-8329-<trimmed>"
```

That is, instead of *foobarbaz*, it'd be nice if Hyprlinkr creates *foo-bar-baz* – similar to the route template, which is `foo-bar-baz/{id}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. That's one of the main reasons for the existence of the `IRouteDispatcher` interface in Hyprlinkr.

Define a custom implementation of `IRouteDispatcher`, like this:

```
public class MyDispatcher : IRouteDispatcher
{
    private readonly IRouteDispatcher dispatcher;

    public MyDispatcher(IRouteDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public Rouple Dispatch(
        MethodCallExpression method,
        IDictionary<string, object> routeValues)
    {
        if (method.Method.ReflectedType == typeof(FooBarBazController))
            return new Rouple("FooBarBazRoute", routeValues);

        return this.dispatcher.Dispatch(method, routeValues);
    }
}
```

Use this to create your `RouteLinker` instance:

```
var linker = new RouteLinker(
    request,
    new MyDispatcher(new DefaultRouteDispatcher()));
```

You can add more special cases to `MyDispatcher.Dispatch` if you have more named routes to which you need to dispatch.